# What's the difference between `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/` directory and `/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/` directory?

Tags: emacs, directory-structure

I use Emacs 23 on my system.  I received a file from a colleague (who has a different Linux distro) to add to the `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/` directory.

As I worked to do this, I noticed another, similarly-named, directory:  `/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/`.  When viewing their contents, I notice that they are not identical.

Is this common with all Emacs configurations on all distros?  Are there distinct purposes for when I should add into one over the other?  Which one?  How do I know?

In short, what is the difference between these 2 directories?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `site-lisp`.  I've never heard of an Emacs with a `site-list` directory.

Comment: I don't have emacs installed, but I'd bet that /usr/share/emacs is a symlink that gets updated on package upgrades to point to the most recent version (emacs23, in this case).

Comment: @Kevin No, it's not a symlink. cjm has it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to have multiple versions of Emacs installed on the same machine.  Only Emacs 23 would load files from `/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/`.  All versions of Emacs would load files from `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/`.

Generally, you just use `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/`, unless there's some reason the code applies only to a particular version of Emacs.

To see where your Emacs is loading code from, type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>    <kbd>v</kbd> `load-path` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cjm's answer, be aware that sometimes `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/` might contain files that will **shadow** the files in a particular emacs installation. I was mad at an error of Emacs25 not being able to find the function `ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic`, until I ran `list-load-path-shadows` and found out that the `ispell.el` file is being shadowed by the `ispell.el` file in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/` which is old and doesn't contain the function!